# How to push an item into my array if the item doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to push in an image if my array index doesn't contain a URL (or it's empty).

I'm using an if statement but am having issues pushing in the item.

```
if( typeof data[t].fullPicture === 'undefined' || data[t].fullPicture === null ){
      console.log(t + "Pushing png")
      data[t].push({fullPicture : "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Empty.png"})
    }
```

What would be the best way to push in the item if it doesn't exist?

Comment: structure of your initial array will help, i.e. `data` I guess

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having? Also if `fullPicture` is a property of `data[t]`, what you probably want to do is `data[t].fullPicture = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/etc..."` and not push to it as if it were an array. It seems that in your example `data` is the array and the elements in it are not arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ( Instead of pushing the data, update the value of the key):

```js
      
if(data[t].fullPicture === 'undefined' || data[t].fullPicture === null) {
  data[t].fullPicture = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/59/Empty.png"
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jim Nilsson Had the right answer.

```
data[t].fullPicture = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/etc..."
```